# Send a jQuery array of ids to Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got the following jQuery variable:

```
var numbers = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

I want to submit a form with these numbers so that my params variable looks like this in the controller:

```
{ 
  "evaluation" =>
  {
     "batch_subject_ids" => ["1", "2", "3"]
  }
}
```

I am creating this array on the fly when I click a button

```
jQuery('<input>').attr({
  type: 'hidden',
  id: 'batch_subject_ids',
  name: 'evaluation[batch_subject_ids][]',
  value: batch_subject_ids
}).appendTo('form');
```

In the controller action, I receive the following params:

```
{ 
  "evaluation" =>
  {
     "batch_subject_ids" => ["1,2,3"]
  }
}
```

I can parse and replace the array, but I was wondering if I could send it from the client with the format I want without having to do that. How can I accomplish this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a read through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters

You need to send separate values of batch_subject_ids[] = 1, batch_subject_ids[] = 2 etc. for this to be turned into an array.